# More efficient function for matching elements and changing classes

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a more efficient way in my function here. I'm matching elements between different areas of my app, changing a form checkbox as well. Obviously there is a lot of redundancy, but I'm not sure about the best way to simplify it since the class names are important. Here is my function:

```js
$(function () {
  $(document).on('click', '#group-element', function() {
    var targets = $('.rectangle.selected');
    $( targets ).each(function() {
      var matchingHeight = $(this).height();
      var matchingWidth = $(this).width();
      $(".rectangle.null").each(function() {
       if ($(this).width() === matchingWidth) {
        $(this).removeClass('matched individual-element missing-element incomplete-element').addClass('group-element');
       }
     });
    });
    $(targets).removeClass('selected individual-element missing-element incomplete-element').addClass('group-element');
    $("#attribute-form .ui.radio.checkbox").removeClass('checked');
    $(".group").prop("checked", true).parent().addClass('checked');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '#individual-element', function() {
    var targets = $('.rectangle.selected');
    $( targets ).each(function() {
      var matchingHeight = $(this).height();
      var matchingWidth = $(this).width();
      $(".rectangle.null").each(function() {
       if ($(this).width() === matchingWidth) {
        $(this).removeClass('matched group-element missing-element incomplete-element').addClass('individual-element');
       }
     });
    });
    $(targets).removeClass('selected group-element missing-element incomplete-element').addClass('individual-element');
    $("#attribute-form .ui.radio.checkbox").removeClass('checked');
    $(".individual").prop("checked", true).parent().addClass('checked');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '#missing-element', function() {
    var targets = $('.rectangle.selected');
    $( targets ).each(function() {
      var matchingHeight = $(this).height();
      var matchingWidth = $(this).width();
      $(".rectangle.null").each(function() {
       if ($(this).width() === matchingWidth) {
        $(this).removeClass('matched group-element individual-element incomplete-element').addClass('missing-element');
       }
     });
    });
    $(targets).removeClass('selected group-element individual-element incomplete-element').addClass('missing-element');
    $("#attribute-form .ui.radio.checkbox").removeClass('checked');
    $(".missing").prop("checked", true).parent().addClass('checked');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '#incomplete-element', function() {
    var targets = $('.rectangle.selected');
    $( targets ).each(function() {
      var matchingHeight = $(this).height();
      var matchingWidth = $(this).width();
      $(".rectangle.null").each(function() {
       if ($(this).width() === matchingWidth) {
        $(this).removeClass('matched group-element missing-element individual-element').addClass('incomplete-element');
       }
     });
    });
    $(targets).removeClass('selected group-element missing-element individual-element').addClass('incomplete-element');
    $("#attribute-form .ui.radio.checkbox").removeClass('checked');
    $(".incomplete").prop("checked", true).parent().addClass('checked');
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about improving/optimizing code are for https://codereview.stackexchange.com rather than SO.

Comment: Reworking functional code is out of scope on StackOverflow.

Comment: Separately: Put the code in a reusable function, and reuse the function.

Comment: A lot of your code is not relevant to your question.  Can you break it down to a single snippet that represents all of the.  This question is in dire need of being a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can DRY this code up by using multiple selectors in the delegated `click` handler.

The only thing that seems different in each function is the class that's added to the `.rectangle.null` element. As it matches the `id` of the clicked element, you can just use the `id` property from that instead:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#group-element, #individual-element, #missing-element, #incomplete-element', function() {
    var el = this;
    $('.rectangle.selected').each(function() {
      var matchingWidth = $(this).width();
      $(".rectangle.null").each(function() {
        if ($(this).width() === matchingWidth) {
          $(this).removeClass('matched individual-element missing-element incomplete-element').addClass(el.id);
        }
      });
    }).removeClass('selected individual-element missing-element incomplete-element').addClass('group-element');

    $("#attribute-form .ui.radio.checkbox").removeClass('checked');
    $(".group").prop("checked", true).parent().addClass('checked');
  });
});
```